# Can I run a python script in arcpy from a .bat file?

Tags: python, batch-file, automation, arcgis, arcpy

I am able to open ArcGIS from the batch file but in order for the script to run successfully I need to be able to run it off the python console within ArcGIS. I can copy and paste the code into the python console within ArcGIS but I want to be able to have the code entered into the console automatically just from the batch file. I'm using ArcGIS 10.6. Is there some file path I should be using? 
Thanks in advance for any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this is rather strange, I don't think I understand the problem here. You want to run Python code from a batch file in the Python console in ArcMap/ArcCatalog?
What is it you want to acomplish?

You can create a standalone Python script, load it in the console and run it.
[image]

If you want to schedule something you can create a Python script and run it in PowerShell or cmd.
If you want something to run in ArcMap/ArcCatalog you can create a model or a script and again can run this anywhere, put it in a toolbox, schedule it, whatever.

If you're a windows user first of all it's nice to have the path to **python.exe** (usually **C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.x**) in your environment variable so you can call it from anywhere. I think PATH should be updated when you install ArcGIS.

When you run Python code in the console you don't need to **import arcpy**, however you do need to import it if you will run it from the command line for example.

You can find a nice GDB administration example here:
https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.6/manage-data/geodatabases/using-python-scripting-to-batch-reconcile-and-post-versions.htm

Careful when dealing with absolute paths, then make sure you're running the script in the same directory.
If you want to define a workspace (some GDB, shapefile or a database connection file) you can reference them like this:

```
myGdb = r"D:\SomeFolder\MyGDB.gdb"
```

Hope this helps if it's relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to the SO community. If I understand you correctly, you do want to run python script from ArcGis's console. You would rather run script from your windows/linux shell/cmd, yes?

SHORT: you should python libs of ARCGis, which you should put into PYTHONPATH enviroment variable. If you configure correctly PYTHONPATH enviroment, then you cound run `python gis_script.py` which utilize ArcGis.

LONG: sometimes you use libraries in python. If you install libraries in your system, before using this libraries, python interpreter should know about these libraries. This configuration is stored in PYTHONPATH enviroment. ArcGis is large python library.

-- edit --

look here: https://community.esri.com/thread/119922 or google: ArcGis PYTHONPATH

Comment: Thanks for responding! Okay so are you saying I should be able to import arcpy into my command window?

Comment: If you would properly set PYTHONPATH environment, then you should be able to import arpy in your cmd

Comment: Ah I see thanks! Any idea why it's giving me "Indentation Error: unexpected error" when I run it even though I don't get that error when running it in ArcGIS?

Comment: Indentation Error Python: first link from gg: https://appuals.com/fix-indentation-error-python/

Comment: But how come I don't get an Indentation Error when I run it in ArcGIS's python console but I do here?

Comment: Can you share the code? Can you show white space characters (spaces, tabulations) of this code?

Comment: Sorry I'm not sure if I'm at liberty to share the code as it is sensitive. I turned it into a .py file so it's no longer giving me Indentation Error but it isn't interacting with ArcMap. It is printing on the condole however so I know I'm doing something right. Any idea how I can get it to interact with ArcMap?

Comment: for me, indentation error means that you incorrectly indented code. Maybe you mix spaces with tabs. And one editor is robust to this problem, and another not. Look at you code, highlight white spaces. Indent error is a problem with your formatting, not with logic